# How to pass a double array(boolean[][]) between activities?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-activity, boolean

I can't see to get a double boolean array to pass through to the another activity. I use putExtra and when I retrieve it and cast it to `boolean[][]`, it states that it can not cast and crashes. Boolean[] works however.

How would I go about passing a `boolean[][]` between activities?

Comment: Do you know the exact dimensions of your 2-dimensional boolean?

Comment: Yes, in this case it is a 3x3 matrix but in the future I would like it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you absolutely need a boolean[][] (and can't do this with just a flat boolean[] array passed to Parcel.writeBooleanArray()), then the formal way to do this is to wrap it in a Parcelable class and do the marshalling/unmarshalling there.

I'll sketch out the code, though this is not tested so there are certainly to be some issues.

```
public class BooleanArrayArray implements Parcelable {
    private final boolean[][] mArray;

    public BooleanArrayArray(boolean[][] array) {
        mArray = array;
    }

    private BooleanArrayArray(Parcelable in) {
        boolean[][] array;
        final int N = in.readInt();
        array = new boolean[][N];
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            array[i] = in.createBooleanArray();
        }
        mArray = array;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        final int N = mArray.length;
        out.writeInt(N);
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            out.writeBooleanArray(mArray[i]);
        }
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<BooleanArrayArray> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<BooleanArrayArray>() {
        public BooleanArrayArraycreateFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new BooleanArrayArray(in);
        }

        public BooleanArrayArray[] newArray(int size) {
            return new BooleanArrayArray[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I have been out so I have not had a chance to try this yet but Im going to give this a shot as this seems to be the best method for me as I would most likely need the two dimensional array. If I run into problems I'll ask and if it works Ill let you know and accept.

Comment: I have been unable to test this as I lost the program. Looking over the code however, this seems like it would work. I'm accepting this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you really require a 2-dimensional array, you can easily convert a 2-dimensional array into a single dimensional array for passing between Activities like so:

```
public boolean[] toOneDimension(boolean[][] input){
    boolean[] output = new boolean[input.length * input[0].length];

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < input[i].length; j++){
            output[i*j] = input[i][j];
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

which you can then build back into a 2-dimensional array like so:

```
public boolean[][] toTwoDimensions(int dimensions, boolean[] input){

    boolean[][] output = new boolean[input.length / dimensions][dimensions];

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        output[i/dimensions][i % dimensions] = input[i];
    }

    return output;
}
```

then use like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int size = 10;

    Random rand = new Random();
    Tester tester = new Tester(); //example code holder
    boolean[][] value = new boolean[size+1][size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size+1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            value[i][j] = rand.nextBoolean();
        }
    }


    boolean [][] output = tester.toTwoDimensions(size, tester.toOneDimension(value));

    for(int i = 0; i < size+1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            assert value[i][j] == output[i][j];
        }
    }


}
```

The only requirement is that you need to know the dimension of your array before you flattened it.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but helped me a lot, so I wanted to share my findings.
I used [Parcelabler](http://www.parcelabler.com/) to make my Object Class Parcelable(Because everything I read, was written in martian to me), then I used @John Ericksen answer to implement it in my Object Class and some methods to make my life easier `flattenMultiDimensionalArray` and `restoreMultiDimensionalArray` and the final result.

For a 2 Dimensional Array

MultiDimensionalArray .java

```
public class MultiDimensionalArray implements Parcelable {

private int[][] multiDimensionalArray;
//Any other Variables, Objects

public MultiDimensionalArray() {

}

public MultiDimensionalArray(int[][] multiDimensionalArray) {

    this.multiDimensionalArray = multiDimensionalArray;
    //Any other Variables, Objects
}

public int[][] getMultiDimensionalArray() {

    return multiDimensionalArray;
}

public void setMultiDimensionalArray(int[][] multiDimensionalArray) {

    this.multiDimensionalArray = multiDimensionalArray;
}

protected MultiDimensionalArray(Parcel in) {

    int rows = in.readInt();
    int columns = in.readInt();
    int[] transitionalArray = in.createIntArray();
    multiDimensionalArray = restoreMultiDimensionalArray(transitionalArray, rows, columns);
    //Any other Variables, Objects

}

@Override
public int describeContents() {

    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    int rows = multiDimensionalArray.length;
    int columns = multiDimensionalArray[rows - 1].length;
    int[] transitionalArray = flattenMultiDimensionalArray(multiDimensionalArray);
    dest.writeInt(rows);
    dest.writeInt(columns);
    dest.writeIntArray(transitionalArray);
    //Any other Variables, Objects

}
public static final Creator<MultiDimensionalArray> CREATOR = new Creator<MultiDimensionalArray>() {

    @Override
    public MultiDimensionalArray createFromParcel(Parcel in) {

        return new MultiDimensionalArray(in);
    }

    @Override
    public MultiDimensionalArray[] newArray(int size) {

        return new MultiDimensionalArray[size];
    }
};
private int[] flattenMultiDimensionalArray(int[][] sourceCard) {

    int k = 0;
    int[] targetCard = new int[sourceCard.length * sourceCard[sourceCard.length - 1].length];
    for (int[] aSourceCard : sourceCard) {
        for (int anASourceCard : aSourceCard) {
            targetCard[k] = anASourceCard;
            k++;
        }
    }
    return targetCard;
}
private int[][] restoreMultiDimensionalArray(int[] sourceCard, int rows, int columns) {

    int k = 0;
    int[][] multiDimensionalArray = new int[rows][columns];
    for (int i = 0; i < multiDimensionalArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < multiDimensionalArray[multiDimensionalArray.length - 1].length; j++) {
            multiDimensionalArray[i][j] = sourceCard[k];
            k++;
        }
    }
    return multiDimensionalArray;
}
```

}