# Receive ArraylistObject getParcelableExtra - NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I cannot figure out how to send and receive and arraylist-object between two categories in android. I get A NullPointerException in activity B.

Activity A

```
 private ArrayList <String[][]> stringObjects2D = new ArrayList <String[][]> () ; 
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CalculationsActivity.class); 
 intent.putExtra("strObj2D", stringObjects2D );
```

Activity B

```
 private ArrayList <String[][]> stringObjects2D;
 stringObjects2D = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("strObj2D");

 // just a check test if something is here. Here I get the NullPointerException
 System.out.println("size = " + stringObjects2D.size());
```

Would be extremely greatful if someone know how to solve this issue.

thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the `String[][]` is not Parcelable. Please use `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` instead.

You can also implement your own Parcelable class to store these data if you think the nested type is too long. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561891/android-how-to-pass-a-double-arrayboolean-between-activities) for implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that implements `Parcelable` and use that class to pass to the intent to insure that you are passing a `parcelable object`.

**sample:**

**UPDATE:**

```
    public class Sample implements Serializable {
    private ArrayList<String[][]> stringObjects2D; 
    public Sample() {
                    stringObjects2D = new ArrayList <String[][]> ();
        String [][] s = {{"1","1"},{"1","1"},{"1","1"},{"1","1"},{"1","1"}};
        stringObjects2D.add(s);
        stringObjects2D.add(s);
        stringObjects2D.add(s);
        stringObjects2D.add(s);
    }
    public ArrayList <String[][]> getArray(){
        return this.stringObjects2D;
    }
```

}

Use in:

```
Sample s2 = new Sample();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class); 
        intent.putExtra("strObj2D", s2);
        startActivity(intent);
```

second activity:

```
 Sample stringObjects2D;
     stringObjects2D = (Sample) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("strObj2D");

     // just a check test if something is here. Here I get the NullPointerException
     System.out.println("size = " + stringObjects2D.getArray().get(0)[0]);
```

Comment: ok thanks, ill look into this in due course of time and maybe accept it.

Comment: I tried with your example and exactly the same happends. I forgot to mention that I could earlier, as you, get the size of the arraylist but not not derefference it (get an individual value). Same Exception: ClassCastException (from Object[] to String[][]). I tried with the following: **System.out.println("array = " + stringObjects2D.getArray().get(1)[0]); **

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
stringObjects2D = (ArrayList<String[][]>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("strObj2D");
```

instead

```
stringObjects2D = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("strObj2D");
```

Comment: I tried that yesterday - sitting for hours not solving it. If I use getSerializableExtra I get a ClassCastExecption instead (cannot cast from Object to string)