# How make an object Parcelable that holds a 2 -dimensional array of a custom object?

Tags: android, parcelable

I have a class A with and inner class B. like the code bellow. I dont know where I am going wrong. What would be the proper way to make Class A Parcelable? Here is how i have right now and its no good. Thanks!

```
public class A implements Parcelable
{
   private B[][] bArray;

   public A(Parcel in)
   {
       bArray = (B[][]) in.readSerializable();
   }

   @Override
   public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i)
   {
   }

   public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
      public A createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
           return new A (in);
      }

      public A[] newArray(int size) {
           return new A[size];
      }
   };



   static class B implements Parcelable
   {
        public B(Parcel in)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i)
        {
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
           public B createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
               return new B(in);
           }

           public B[] newArray(int size) {
               return new B[size];
           }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561891/android-how-to-pass-a-double-arrayboolean-between-activities

Comment: Always keep separate question for each problem